# Firebase Login with google Stopped working

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a firebase app that uses this block of code to log people in either with facebook or with google.

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup(provider, function (error, authData) {
          console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
        }, {
          remember: "sessionOnly",
          scope: "email"
        });
```

Today when I ran it it stopped working. I can see in the console that the code is running but the pop up doesn't show up and i get an Error that I cant get uid of undefined I tried replacing it with this chunk of code

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function (error, authData) {}, {
    remember: "sessionOnly",
    scope: "email"
  });
```

but I still get nothing when it runs. Any insight you can give on the situation would be appreciated.

Comment: I can get it to run now when I deploy to a web server but it still doesn't work when I run it locally